# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xsbti/AppConfiguration at sbt.Main.main(Main.scala)

Tags: scala, jenkins, sbt

No Class Definition Error in sbt Jenkins job
**Error while running build using sbt in Jenkins Freestyle Job**

```
The following error was encountered while building sbt project in Jenkins:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xsbti/AppConfiguration

         at sbt.Main.main(Main.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xsbti.AppConfiguration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
Build step 'Build using sbt' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Build using sbt' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

sbt:

```
sbtPlugin := true 
name := "sbt-findbugs" 
organization := "uk.co.josephearl" 
version := "2.4.4-SNAPSHOT" 

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.sf.saxon" % "Saxon-HE" % "9.4", 
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.2.1" % "test",
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.11" % "test") 

scalaVersion := "2.10.4" 
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-language:_") 

licenses += ("EPL-1.0", url("eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html")) 

publishMavenStyle := false 

publishArtifact in Test := false
```

Comment: Please, post your code as well.

Comment: sbtPlugin := true

name := "sbt-findbugs"

organization := "uk.co.josephearl"

version := "2.4.4-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.sf.saxon" % "Saxon-HE" % "9.4",
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.2.1" % "test",
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.11" % "test"
)

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-language:_")

licenses += ("EPL-1.0", url("https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"))

publishMavenStyle := false

publishArtifact in Test := false

Comment: https://github.com/josephearl/sbt-findbugs - code